# Can a landlord charge an addendum fee to add/drop a name on an existing lease

Tags: united-states, rent, tenant, washington

Can a landlord charge an addendum fee of $250 to add/drop a name on an existing lease in Washington State, USA?

Answer (score 1):

You are negotiating a change to an existing contract - it can be concluded on any terms the parties agree. If the landlords terms are a fee of $250 then the tenants can agree and proceed or not agree and not proceed.

Comment: Landlord-tenant/tenancy law often goes above and beyond the usual contract law, and often restricts what may or may not be a term or a consideration for those contracts, especially when they involve fees mandated by the landlord. A bit of reference to relevant reasonableness tests or fees permitted/forbidden would actually answer the question. As it is, this is just Contracts 101.